# Enable Accept-Encoding and Keep-Alive in the response header for an xml file (IIS)

Tags: xml, iis, httpresponse, keep-alive

I have an xml file on my website and a third party company is having trouble reading that file at the moment. I put exactly the same file to amazon cloud, and it worked for them. So I guess there could be some server configuration I need to work on.

There are some differences in the response header that I can see between the amazon server (working) and my server (not working). On my server I don't seem to have the followings in my response header when requesting the xml file,

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

It would be great if someone can suggest on how to enable them on my IIS 7.5, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## Enable the HTTP Keep-Alive Response Header (IIS 7)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772183(v=ws.10).aspx